# Xamarin Forms keyboard remaining even Editor is not visible (How to wait other task thread to complete? )

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**[Github repository](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/63592854) to reproduce issue.**

I am working on Xamarin Forms to create an app.

```
<StackLayout>
    <Editor x:Name="Editor"
            Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </Editor>
    <Button x:Name="Button"
            Text="Complete"
            Command="{Binding CompleteCommand}" />
</StackLayout>
```

I am trying to lock focus on `Editor` when `ContentView` is **Visible**.

Therefore, I use `Editor.Unfocused` event to lock focus like below.

```
public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
    private void OnEditorUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsVisible)
        {
            Editor.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

I register and unregister `OnEditorUnfocused` method when `ContentView.IsVisible` property changed like below.

```
public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanging([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // IsVisible changes from "True" to "False"
        if (propertyName.Equals("IsVisible") && IsVisible)
        {
            Editor.Unfocused -= OnEditorUnfocused;
            Editor.Unfocus();
        }

        base.OnPropertyChanging(propertyName);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // IsVisible changed from "False" to "True"
        if (propertyName.Equals("IsVisible") && IsVisible)
        {
            Editor.Unfocused += OnEditorUnfocused;
            Editor.Focus();
        }

        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Here I encounter an issue. `Editor.Focus()` and `Editor.Unfocus()` does not apply immediately. And when `ContentView` is not visible, first `Editor.Focus()` does not work. Furthermore, when `ContentView.Visible` changes from `True` to `False` by `Button`, Keyboard remains on screen.

Therefore I change my code like below,

```
public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
        private Task _focusEditorTask;
        private Task _unfocusEditorTask;

        public event EventHandler LostFocused;

        public MyView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _focusEditorTask = _unfocusEditorTask = Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void OnEditorUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsVisible)
            {
                FocusEditor();
                Console.WriteLine($"<Unfocused> Editor: Focused {Editor.IsFocused}");
            }
        }

        private void FocusEditor()
        {
            _unfocusEditorTask.Wait();
            _focusEditorTask.Wait();

            _focusEditorTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"<FocusEditor> START {Editor.IsFocused}");

                while (!Editor.IsFocused)
                {
                    Editor.Focus();
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    Console.WriteLine($"<FocusEditor> PROGRESS {Editor.IsFocused}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"<FocusEditor> END {Editor.IsFocused}");
            });
        }

        private void UnfocusEditor()
        {
            _focusEditorTask.Wait();
            _unfocusEditorTask.Wait();

            _unfocusEditorTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"<!UnfocusEditor> START {Editor.IsFocused}");
                while (Editor.IsFocused)
                {
                    Editor.Unfocus();
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    Console.WriteLine($"<!UnfocusEditor> PROGRESS {Editor.IsFocused}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"<!UnfocusEditor> END {Editor.IsFocused}");

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanging([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (propertyName.Equals("IsVisible") && IsVisible)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"<IsVisibleChanging> InputView: IsVisible ({IsVisible}) -> {!IsVisible}");
                Editor.Unfocused -= OnEditorUnfocused;
                UnfocusEditor();
            }

            base.OnPropertyChanging(propertyName);
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (propertyName.Equals("IsVisible") && IsVisible)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"<IsVisibleChanged> InputView: IsVisible {!IsVisible} -> ({IsVisible})");
                Editor.Unfocused += OnEditorUnfocused;
                FocusEditor();
            }

            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
}
```

Now I have only one problem, `Wait()` does not effective.

Here is **Application Output** depends on `ContnetView.IsVisible` changes,

#### 1. change `ContnetView.IsVisible` from **false** to **true**

```
    <IsVisibleChanged> InputView: IsVisible False -> (True)
    <FocusTextEditor> START False
    <FocusTextEditor> PROGRESS False
    <FocusTextEditor> PROGRESS True
    <FocusTextEditor> END True
```

#### 2. change `ContentView.IsVisible` from **true** to **false** by `Button`

```
    <Unfocused> TextEditor: Focused False
    <FocusTextEditor> START False
    <IsVisibleChanging> InputView: IsVisible (True) -> False
    // START should not fire...
    <!UnfocusTextEditor> START False
    <!UnfocusTextEditor> END False
    // because of this, keyboard does not disappear even ContnetView is not visible.
    <FocusTextEditor> PROGRESS True
    <FocusTextEditor> END True
```

[image: Keyboard remain]

Comment: `Editor.Unfocus()` - what if you focus some other control instead?

Comment: @aepot Unfortunately I already try that. Focusing `Button` does not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Task.Factory.StartNew()` is [not awaitable this way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/psychic-debugging-of-async-methods/). Because it returns `Task<Task>` here, not `Task` and inner `Task` must be awaited then. But you may simply change it to `Task.Run()` and fix this completely. And finally you don't need a Threading here. The job can be done simply with asynchronous calls without invoking a `Task.Run()`.
2. You're interacting with UI from pooled Thread, that's not OK.
3. You locking UI Thread with `.Wait()`, that's bad practice and may freeze UI or cause a deadlock in some cases.
4. You may subscribe to the Event once.

I'm not familiar with Xamarin but know well the [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Here's my try to rewrite the code.

```csharp
public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnEditorUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Editor.IsVisible)
        {
            Editor.Focus();
            Console.WriteLine($"<Unfocused> Editor: Focused {Editor.IsFocused}");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (propertyName == nameof(IsVisible))
        {
            if (IsVisible)
            {
                Editor.Focus();
                Editor.Unfocused += OnEditorUnfocused;
            }
            else
            {
                Editor.Unfocused -= OnEditorUnfocused;
                Editor.Unfocus();
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"<IsVisibleChanged> InputView: IsVisible {!IsVisible} -> ({IsVisible})");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I applied your solution to reproduction code and infinitely await on `FocusEditorAsync()` It must caused by `while` loop. `Editor.IsFocused` does not changing!  [Applied Code on Github](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/63592854%40aepot) I think it is not only related with **Asynchronous Programming**... so sad..

Comment: @ibocon maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169827/12888024) may help then as initial focus.

Comment: the answer you provide, [Setting the Focus to an Entry in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169029/setting-the-focus-to-an-entry-in-xamarin-forms/31169827#31169827), only work one time when `Page` appearing. What I do is change `Visible` when button clicked. And initial `Visible` is `False`. Also `OnAppearing()` method does not exist in [`ContentView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentview?view=xamarin-forms)

Comment: @ibocon Maybe check if `Editor.IsVisible` instead of View's `IsVisible`? Updated the answer.

Comment: @ibocon _Applied Code on Github_ you've forgot to update `OnPropertyChanging` and `OnPropertyChanged` there. Btw, you can remove these methods completely. Maybe infinite `await` caused there as a deadlock because of `.Wait()` not allowed there. Move the event subsctiption to the constructor as i showed.

Comment: First of all, thanks to working with my question! I update _Code_ and solve deadlock. but, still having a keyboard remaining issue and initial focus failing issue.

Comment: @ibocon let's clarify. Is it correct: Editor must gain Focus when become visible and loose it when hidden, right?

Comment: yes, Editor always get focus when visible, and loose it when hidden.