# Focus Entry in a Custom Control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

how can i set a focus for a Entry nested in a custom control?

PackageCode.xaml

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="this"
      
         x:Class="Views.Controls.PackageCode">

<Entry x:Name="txtPackageCode" Completed="txtPackageCode_Completed"> </Entry>
```

I have tried with txtPackageCode.Focus();

```
  public PackageCode()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtPackageCode.Focus();

    }
```

Nested in my Main.xaml

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                
        <local:PackageCode  ></local:PackageCode>
        

        <Button Text="ClickMe"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"    ></Button>

    </StackLayout>
   


</ContentPage.Content>
```

And How to extract the value of this Entry in my Main.xaml?

Comment: you need to expose a public method in your control that the page can call

Comment: what kind of public method i need for a foucs? OnAppearing is not working for ContentView

Answer (score 0):

add a public method in `PackageCode`

```
public void Focus()
{
  txtPackageCode.Focus();
}
```

then call it from `Main`

```
public override void OnAppearing()
{
    // you will need to assign an x:Name in the XAML
    packageCode.Focus();
}
```

Comment: not working on Android or UWP.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await Task.Delay(1);
    packageCode.SetFocus();
}
```

This worked.
[Setting the Focus to an Entry in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169029/setting-the-focus-to-an-entry-in-xamarin-forms/31169827)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.